# Add File to newly created Subfolder

Tags: c#

In my webApi controller method.. when a user creates a new record.. a new sub-folder is created based on one of the properties that the user submitted to the controller:

```
// create directory

string path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/Content/Uploads/DailyTickets/" + userSubmittedObject.Name);

if (Directory.Exists(path)) // check if path already exists
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "This Name Already Exists!");
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}

DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

This works.. however when I check the Solution Explorer to see if the folder is created.. it is not there.  The only way I can verify if the folder was created is if I go into File Explorer and go to the actual path where this project is saved.  I think this is because this folder doesn't have anything inside of it when it is created.  So I have created a `.txt` document and added it to the Solution.  The `.txt` file is just a filler document so that folders will appear in solution explorer.

My question is.. how do I add that `.txt` file to the newly created folder?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `File.Create(path + "pewpew.txt").Close();`

Comment: You can copy the file using `File.Copy(@"c:\path\file.txt", Path.Combine(di.FullName, "new_file.txt"));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to copy the specific file you can use `File.Copy` like this:

```
File.Copy(@"c:\path\file.txt", Path.Combine(di.FullName, "new_file.txt"));
```

If you just want to create a placeholder file you can do so by using `File.Create`

```
File.Create(Path.Combine(di.FullName, "new_file.txt")).Close();
```

Comment: Okay, the `File.Create` is working.. but it's strange.. I still can't see the new folder in Solution Explorer.. I can only see it when I manually go to the folder through File Explorer.  Any ideas?

Comment: I apologize if I click 'Show All Files' then I can see it, but the folder icon is just a dotted-outline along with the `new_file.txt` document.  Any reason for that?

Comment: Lol nvmd I am figuring all of this out on my own haha

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid nice :)